# Beginner attempt to make a text input dialog box Java, Infinite loop in result

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, infinite-loop

What I basically wanted to do was a text box, which checks the text for specific mistakes and then increments few variables. It should give to the display some details at prompt or exit the program. After each code entry i should be able to write another one and so on until i exit with the proper "XXX" text. What happens tho is that when i enter a code: a) the code is right - the box freezes or b)the code is wrong - infinite loop. I need some guidance on which part of the code I am wrong and how to exit the infinite loop.

Sample codes: 3956P9R-14, 2324A7R-12, 27Y5P5R-10

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Button extends JFrame{

public Button()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel enterYourCode = new JLabel("Enter the code here:");
    JTextField textBoxToEnterCode = new JTextField(21);
    JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
    panelTop.add(enterYourCode);
    panelTop.add(textBoxToEnterCode);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterCode));
    submit.addKeyListener(new SubmitButton(textBoxToEnterCode));
    JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
    panelBottom.add(submit);

    //Add panelTop to JFrame
    add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //JFrame set-up
    setTitle("Code Prompt Program");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    submit.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(submit);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Button frame = new Button();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And the other class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SubmitButton implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

JTextField nameInput;
protected JTextField textInputField;
protected JTextArea textArea;
private static int totalCodes;
private static int validCodes;
private static int invalidCodes;
private static int disallowedCodes;

public SubmitButton(JTextField textfield){
    textInputField = textfield;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent submitClicked) {

    String code = null;
    String subCode = null;
    do{
    code = textInputField.getText();
    totalCodes++;       
    int codeLength;         
    codeLength = code.length();
    if(code.equals("XXX"))
        break;
    else if(codeLength == 10)
    {   

        subCode = code.substring(0, 4);
        try {
            int bankrollCode = Integer.parseInt(subCode);

            char financialPos = code.charAt(6);
            switch(financialPos){
            case 'R':   if(bankrollCode<2500){
                Component frame = new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "Insufficient Funds!");
                disallowedCodes++;
                validCodes++;
            }else validCodes++;

            }

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            invalidCodes++;
            Component frame = new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "Code is invalid, Please enter a valid Code");
        }
    }
    else if(code.equals("show"))
    {
        Component frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "Total number of codes entered: " + (totalCodes-1) + "\n\nValid Codes: " + validCodes + "\nInvalid Codes: " + invalidCodes + "\nDisallowed Codes: " + disallowedCodes);
    }
    else
    {
        invalidCodes++;
        Component frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "Enter a valid code!");
    }
}while(!code.equals("XXX"));    }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    Component frame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame , "You've Submitted the name " + nameInput.getText());

}

public void actionPerformedtwo(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text = textInputField.getText();        
    textArea.append(text);
    textInputField.selectAll();
    }

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `do-while-loop`. Every time the user pushes the submit button, the entered code should be checked only once.
And don't forget to initialize the variable `totalCodes`.